# is it possible to migrate AWS EC2 instance to AWS Lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, migration, amazon-lightsail

I need to move a couple of EC2 instances to Lightsail.

There are some ways of exporting Lightsail->EC2 using snapshot image but cannot find any info on how to do it the other way around EC2->Lightsail.

Is the migration EC2->Lightsail possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can only migrate lightsail instances to EC2.

Answer (score -2):

Try to create new Lightsail instance as per your requirement and then points IP address. last steps is terminate your old EC2 instance.